# how to use mysql function in python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to insert a date in a table by using MySQL function select curdate(), here's how the code looks like:

`cur.execute("insert into attendance values(%s,%s,%s)",(input("enter absentee name  "),select curdate(),"absent"))`

it's showing syntax error

[image: here's a screenshot of the error]

Comment: Can you provide us the complete error message?

Comment: ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Your screenshot is not safe. Make the window as wide as possible, until the whole statement is in one line. Then show a part of the window which shows both caret and code part under it.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow, thanks for the help. Will make sure to get the right ss next time, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe simply

```
cur.execute("insert into attendance values(%s,curdate(),%s)",(input("enter absentee name  "),"absent"))
```

?

Comment: @GauravMeena I cannot predict the error message - show its **complete** text.

Comment: runfile('E:/school attendance 2.0.py', wdir='E:')
  File "E:\school attendance 2.0.py", line 7
    cur.execute("insert into attendance values(%s,curdate(),%s)",(input("enter absentee name  "),select curdate(),"absent"))
                                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @GauravMeena What symbol/place is posessed under the caret `^` symbol?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the error in  the question itself hope that helps

Comment: thnx that code is working, I forgot to remove the select curdate(), thanks

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error comes from `select currdate()` not being in a string.  It's not valid python.

```
cur.execute("insert into attendance values(%s,%s,%s)",(input("enter absentee name  "),select curdate(),"absent"))
```

As for achieving what you are trying to do, Try

```
cur.execute("insert into attendance values(%s,curdate(),%s)",(input("enter absentee name  "),"absent"))
```

Comment: yep already tried that, it still shows syntax error.

Comment: Is it a Python syntax error or an SQL syntax error?  The above by itself is valid python.  Can you paste your full file and or the entire error?  The Syntax error message will typically give you an indicator of exactly where it thinks the problem is.

Comment: just added the error screenshot in the question itself hope that helps

Comment: ok my yes your answer is right I forgot to remove select curdate() thank you so much